# Using make to translate reST files

Tags: makefile, restructuredtext, gnu-make

I have a bunch of text files in the `help_pages/` directory, all formatted in reST. I'm trying to add to my GNU make `Makefile` a couple of rules that:

1. Run each file in the `help_pages` directory (and sub-directories) with the extension '.rst' through an app that spits out a valid html file (right now I'm just using `rst2html`).
2. Copy those output html files to a target directory, reproducing the directory structure that existed in the `help_pages` directory.

So, for example, `help_pages/some/dir/foo.rst` would first get translated to `help_pages/some/dir/foo.html`, and then copied to `public/help/some/dir/foo.html`.

I've spent all day trying to learn the intracacies of Makefiles, but in the end I gave up. Here's what I have already:

```
# Directory that the .rst files reside in:
HELP_DIR=help_pages
# use 'find' to locate all such files:
HELP_SRCS=$(shell find $(HELP_DIR) -name "*.rst")
# work out what path the intermediate files would be
HELP_TARGETS=$(HELP_SRCS:.rst=.html)

# do the translation.   
$(HELP_TARGETS): %.html: %.rst
        rst2html $< $@

help: $(HELP_TARGETS) 

.phony:
        help
```

This kind-of works - the .rst files get translated to .html files, but I have no idea how to install them into the final, target directory. If I add a `cp` command to the main build recipe, the files are not re-installed if they don't exist in the target directory.

Ideally I'd like a target to make the help files, and one to install them, and a third (called 'help') that depends on these two. I think this will give me the greatest flexibility.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to achieve this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I've spent all day trying to learn the intracacies of Makefiles, but in the end I gave up."* You don't know how funny that is.

This should do it:

```
HELP_DIR=help_pages
# use 'find' to locate all such files:
HELP_SRCS=$(shell find $(HELP_DIR) -name "*.rst")
# work out what path the intermediate files would be
HELP_TARGETS=$(HELP_SRCS:.rst=.html)
# and the destinations
HELP_INSTALL = $(patsubst help_pages%,public%,$(HELP_TARGETS))

# do the translation.
$(HELP_TARGETS): %.html: %.rst
    rst2html $< $@          

# do the installation
$(HELP_INSTALL):public/%:help_pages/%
    cp $< $@

.PHONY: help install

help: $(HELP_TARGETS)

install:$(HELP_INSTALL)
```

Now if you want to do everything, just `make install`. Or if you want to create the html files without copying them into `public/`, just `make help`. You'll find that the dependencies work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`make` has "smart" treatment of pathnames with directory separators which makes it a royal pain to write rules that do things across different directories.

One workaround is to do the copying as a side effect of the conversion, e.g. adding something this as a second command might work:

```
echo $@ | cpio -pdl public/html
```

BTW, `.PHONY` is in capitals.